# How standard is Acumatica BQL Syntax

Tags: c#, acumatica

I was speaking with someone who used BQL in another product. He said that if Acumatica is compliant with Bloomberg standards, it should be able to do syntax like this:

```
public class FooGraph : PXGraph
{
    public PXSelect<FSAppointment> Appointments;
    public PXSelect<FSAppointmentDet, 
      Where<FSAppointmentDet.refNbr, 
      Equal<Current<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>> AppointmentDetails;

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        // Execute the BQL query by JOINING the two PXSelects
         var query = Appointments.Join(AppointmentDetails).
             Where(a => a.RefNbr == "0001");
        var result = query.Select().FirstOrDefault();

        // Use the result
        if (result != null)
        {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    }
}
```

I like this approach because sometimes when a lot of Joins and Wheres get strung together, I find it easy to lose the pattern (not to mention something like a dozen >>>>> at the end!)

But I can't seem to find a way of making the above syntax work.

Is it possible to work with a PXSelect in sections similar to this and then simply add the Joins and Wheres later?

Any examples you can point me to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t join statements this way, but there’s a solution to increase readability and maintainability of complex BQL statements - [fluent BQL](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/fluent-bql-increase-the-readability-maintainability-of-your-queries/).